# Python and MySQL-Connector-Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

note I am using the following version of Python on a Windows OS:

```
(venv) C:\>python
    Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

*The following Python script below is run and the output is shown directory below it. Most of this script has been used from the following source:

https://pynative.com/python-mysql-select-query-to-fetch-data/

**SCRIPT 1**

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
try:
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='coldplay123',
                                  host='localhost',
                                  database='nathan_test_1')

    cursor_1 = cnx.cursor()
    s1="select * from dataframe"
    cursor_1.execute(s1)
    data1 = cursor_1.fetchall()

    print("Total number of dataframes: ", cursor_1.rowcount)

    for i1 in data1:
        print(i1)
    cursor_1.close()

except Error as e1:
    print("Failure to connect ... ", e1)

cnx.close()
```

**Output of SCRIPT 1**

```
Total number of dataframes:  1
('a', 'b', 'c', 699)
```

*Now, I change just two lines from Script 1
in the middle by simply commenting them out 
and the following output is generated:

**SCRIPT 2**

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
try:
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='coldplay123',
                                  host='localhost',
                                  database='nathan_test_1')

    cursor_1 = cnx.cursor()
    #s1="select * from nathan"
    #cursor_1.execute(s1)
    data1 = cursor_1.fetchall()

    print("Total number of dataframes: ", cursor_1.rowcount)

    for i1 in data1:
        print(i1)
    cursor_1.close()

except Error as e1:
    print("Failure to connect ... ", e1)

cnx.close()
```

**Output of SCRIPT 2**

```
Failure to connect ...  No result set to fetch from.
```

*It is easy to see what causes this error, but *why* does not
allowing 'cursor_1' to execute a given SQL query cause this 
error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [PEP 249 - Python Database API Specification v2.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)
, [`fetchone`, `fetchmany`, `fetchall` documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchone),

> An Error (or subclass) exception is raised if the previous call to .execute*() did not produce any result set or no call was issued yet.

`fetch*()` call should be followed by `execute` call.